# terminal in raw mode - stty(1)

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, pty

from an ESXi 5.0 shell I would have access to a VM virtual serial interface (VM is running on the ESXi hypervisor). Using netcat (nc) available on ESXi, is possible to connect to the VM virtual serial interface via a UNIX socket binded to it (named pipe).

Now, to emulate a "real" terminal connected to the VM serial interface, I've set the pseudo-terminal in raw mode via "stty raw" command (issued on ESXi shell). Access to the OS running in the VM is fine but I can see that sent characters are echoed back

I've tried passing -echo to stty without lucky: the terminal seem blocked and the only way to recover is disconnect and riconnect again...

Someone can help me ?

---

I've solved concatenating stty and nc as follows:

stty raw -echo; nc -U 'unix socket'

which is the difference between stty and nc "concatenation" via ";" and just run the two commands one after the other ("stty raw -echo" and then "nc -U unix socket") ?

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and collect your first 15 points in reputation! (I think you may have to wait 48 hrs to accept your own answer). Interesting stuff, keep posting!

Comment: Also, you may find http://www.amazon.com/termcap-terminfo-OReilly-Nutshell-Linda/dp/0937175226/ref=sr_1_9?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1415804017&sr=1-9&keywords=oreilly+books+terminal to be some help if you have further digging on `stty`. Good luck.